# Azure Synapse Pipelines -- I think I broke it. "The Pipeline update_fastq_queue is in an unsupported state: Renaming"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

So I created a new version of a routine, and wanted to replace the current version with the new one.  So I renamed the old routine to update_fastq_queue_retired, then renamed the new routine to update_fastq_queue_retired, and pressed Publish.  It indicated it was Publishing, and then just sat there forever.  I waited an extended period of time, then opened a new browser window to peek and discovered this -- the old version was still there, a copy of the old version with the _retired name had appeared, and the new version hadn't been renamed.

I waited a bit longer, but finally refreshed the original page.  Same state.

So . . . I deleted the old version with the old name, and pressed Publish.  I get the error "**The Pipeline update_fastq_queue is in an unsupported state: Renaming**".  I'm blocked from proceeding, and it's been an hour now.  Am I stuck with this old version with the original name forever?  How do I clear that file for proper flushing?  Will it time out eventually, and if so, how long?

Is there a way to clear the "Renaming" state from the file?

Comment: Oh, the ongoing horrors of Synapse Publish issues. This is actually a new one for me, and I thought I had seen them all. My only suggestion is to put in a support ticket.

Comment: My client is happy they're saving money on the software cost, paying me by the hour to deal with a tool that won't let you rename a file.  I've opened a ticket.

Comment: For the record, I'm a big Synapse fan, but I dislike the Git integration and Publish design. I have seen issues with renames, but it's usually a timing issue around multiple pull requests where an asset is renamed before ever getting published. That being said, I've never seen a Publish state issue like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of an answer -- when I got into work this morning this had all cleared itself up.  So apparently it took Azure a 12 hour window to complete the Rename action.

Very happy I'm paid by the hour with Azure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).